# Type does not conform to Identifiable when decoding JSON data

Tags: json, swift

Im trying to use a different json file for my app. The original json file has `"id"` in it but the new json file has `"nr"`. So I changed my code to this:

```
import Foundation

struct Pokemon: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let nr: Int
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let type: String
}
```

Earlier code had `let id: Int` instead of `let nr: Int`.
After changing this code, I get the error:

> Type pokemon does not conform to protocol identifiable

This was the old json file:

```
{
    "attack": 49,
    "defense": 49,
    "description": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight.\nThere is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun’s rays,\nthe seed grows progressively larger.",
    "evolutionChain": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "ivysaur"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "venusaur"
      }
    ],
    "height": 7,
    "id": 1,
    "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pokedex-bb36f.appspot.com/o/pokemon_images%2F2CF15848-AAF9-49C0-90E4-28DC78F60A78?alt=media&token=15ecd49b-89ff-46d6-be0f-1812c948e334",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "type": "poison",
    "weight": 69
  },
```

Whereas new file has `"nr"` instead of `"id"`:

```
{
    "nr": 1,
    "nrp": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "class": "Seed Pok\u00e9mon",
    "icon": "https:\/\/s6.postimg.org\/z17mvgtgx\/001.png",
    "art": "https:\/\/s6.postimg.org\/bu799hi5t\/001.png",
    "types": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
```

I found after searching that I need to use id as it is used as identifier. How to use that "nr" instead of id? Or any other way to use id in new json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computable property, like

```
struct Pokemon: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int { nr }                       // << here !!
    let nr: Int
    let name: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let type: String
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it asks me to define "nr" but it won't let me define nr anywhere. I tried "let nr: Int" above "let id: Int {nr}" but still no solution.